# Relating two seemingly different definitions of Riemannian metric.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, definition, positive-definite, matrix-analysis

I've been studying Riemannian geometry from John M. Lee's book on the same. My aim is to understand the geometry of Hermitian positive semidefinite matrices when viewed as a Riemannian manifold.

In Lee's book (and Wikipedia), the Riemannian metric (tensor) $g$ is defined as a smooth 2-covariant tensor field on a manifold $M$. Equivalently, for every point $p \in M$, it smoothly assigns an 2-covariant tensor (which can be interpreted as an inner product) of the form

$$ g(p) \equiv g_p : T_pM \times T_pM \to \mathbb{R}. $$

Due to the inner product nature, one can also denote it as

$$ g_p(X,Y)  \equiv \langle X, Y \rangle_p, $$
for $X, Y \in T_pM$.

This is a definition of the Riemannian tensor I'm comfortable with.

However, in the book '[Positive Definite Matrices](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691168258/positive-definite-matrices)' by Rajendra Bhatia, he defines the metric via a differential. Here the manifold is the set of $n \times n$ Positive definite matrices $ \mathbb P_n$, and for a point $A \in \mathbb P_n$, the tangent space is $T_A \mathbb P_n = {A} \times \mathbb H_n \cong \mathbb H_n$, where $\mathbb H_n$ is the space of $n \times n$ Hermitian matrices.

The author states that the inner-product on $ \mathbb H_n$ (defined as $\langle A, B \rangle := \operatorname{Tr}[A^*B]$) leads to a Riemannian metric on the manifold $ \mathbb P_n$. He then says that 'at a point $A$ this metric is given by the differential'

$$ ds = || A ^{-1/2} dA A ^{-1/2} ||_2 = (\operatorname{Tr}[(A ^{-1} d A)^2])^{1/2},  $$

where the $|| \cdot ||$ denotes the Hilbert-Schmidt norm defined as $||A||_2 = \sqrt{\langle A,A \rangle }$.

What is the equivalence between Bhatia's definition and Lee's definition of the metric tensor?
What is the right way of interpreting differential here ($ds$ and $dA$)? The interpretation of 'differential' I'm comfortable with is the way John M. Lee defines it, where the differential of a smooth function is a particular kind of covector field.

PS. Am I missing any keyword which would help with looking up for references? I think this has to do induced metric, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${\rm d}s$ is a standard notation for the line element ${\rm d}s = (g_{ij}\,{\rm d}x^i\,{\rm d}x^j)^{1/2}$, while $A$ is also used to denote a "global coordinate" on $\mathbb{P}_n$. It is $g_A(B,B)^{1/2} = \|A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}\|_2 = \big({\rm Tr}[(A^{-1}B)^2]\big)^{1/2}$ whenever $A\in \mathbb{P}_n$ and $B\in T_A\mathbb{P}_n$. Then polarize this formula to find $g_A(B,C)$ for $B,C\in T_A\mathbb{P}_n$.

Comment: Could you also tell me (or point to a reference) what 'polarize' means in this context?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity

Comment: Thanks. I was able to polarize to obtain $g_A(B,C)$. I have another question being that how did you establish the form of $g_A(B,B)$ in your answer?

Comment: It is from the meaning of ${\rm d}s^2$. People with either physics or classical surface theory in mind usually think of ${\rm d}s^2$ as being the metric tensor $g$, writing things like ${\rm d}s^2(v,v) = g(v,v)$. If $A$ is a position in $\mathbb{P}_n$, the infinitesimal version ${\rm d}A$ is a tangent vector at $A$. So I just replaced ${\rm d}A$ with $B$.